# How can one draw such 3D sketch/diagrams?

Tags: graphics3d

The image below is taken from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jqsrt.2019.06.025), which also contains other similar 3D images.

[image: sphere]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Most likely this is done with TikZ, not with Mathematica. You can find similar examples here: [https://tikz.net/axis3d/](https://tikz.net/axis3d/)

Comment: Yes, most probably, but the question is, *can* it be done with MMA?

Comment: Yes, it can be done, but there are a lot of elements and details. Not sure how many folks will be willing to spend time creating a high fidelity copy of that. Have you tried anything at all yet? Are there specific elements that you already know how to create (so we can focus on what you're struggling with)? How close to that image do you need to get? Are your questions more with the graphic elements or with styling? Do you even need to create that specific image or do you just want some instruction on basic graphics capabilities in Mathematica?

Comment: Well, I first wanted to see if MMA is suitable as a tool for this, compared to tikz/inkscape etc. Secondly, I wouldn't know where to start implementing this. I don't need an exact replica of the sketch, just *something* that would contain at least some of the elements present.

Comment: The community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you: 
❌: A clear description of an on-topic narrow and specifi problem or goal.
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
❌. An example of what you expect as output.
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge. 
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This involves quite some work. Her is a simple example to get you going:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
quartercircle[phi_, rad_ : 1] = 
  Table[rad {Cos[phi] Cos[the], Sin[phi] Cos[the], Sin[the]}, {the, 0,
     Pi/2, Pi/20}];
line[phi_, the_, dashed_ : False] = {Thick, If[dashed, Dashed], 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {Cos[phi] Cos[the], Sin[phi] Cos[the], 
      Sin[the]}}]};
arrow[phi_, the_, dashed_ : False, 
  txt_ : ""] = {tmp = line[phi, the, dashed], 
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, 1.3 tmp[[-1, -1, -1]]}], 
  If[txt =!= "", Text[txt, 1.4 tmp[[-1, -1, -1]]]]}

Graphics3D[{Line[{quartercircle[0], quartercircle[Pi/4], 
    quartercircle[Pi/4, 0.3]}], line[0.2, 0, True], 
  line[Pi/4, 0, True], line[Pi/2, 0, True], 
  arrow[Pi/4, Pi/4, True, \[Omega]], arrow[0, 0, False, "X"], 
  arrow[Pi/2, 0, False, "Y"], arrow[0, Pi/2, False, "Z"], 
  Opacity[0.2], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {0, 1.5}}]
```

[image]